# Format string at runtime

Tags: asp.net, string-formatting

I'm creating a html table at runtime (no probs there), and I would like to be able to format the content in the cells at runtime by passing in a format string (ie currencies, decimals, decimal places etc)

for example, i want to achieve something like this but to be able to pass in the format of the string with code as a string, ie `"{0:c}"` or `"#,###,###"`

ideally to be able to pass it into the `ToString()` method ( i can't do that but was wondering if there could be a clever way to achieve this?)

```
tblCell.Text = dt.Rows[i][j].ToString(#.##);
```

Comment: where does the data for the html table come from? Would GridView or ListView an option? I added an answer to show what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

```
tblCell.Text = String.Format("{0:c}", dt.Rows[i][j])
```

and

```
tblCell.Text = String.Format("{0:#.##}", dt.Rows[i][j])
```

should work.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at:
http://www.cheat-sheets.org/saved-copy/msnet-formatting-strings.pdf

I always use this cheat sheet to find out things like these as the number of possibilities is simply to big to remember them all

Comment: Links seems to be down. :-(

Answer (score 0):

You can supply format strings to the columns in your GridView by setting the DataFormatString property of the column to something like this:  “{0:d}”.